# Open in + UIDocumentInteractionController : how to filter options in SDK iOS 6 (canPerformActions is deprecated)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, uidocumentinteraction

Since the new SDK was release (iOS 6), the delegate method `documentInteractionController:canPerformAction:` of the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` is deprecated.

Using that method you were able to prevent default actions like `print:` and `copy:` to appear.

The method is being called in the current version of iOS 6, but in future versions this method will not be called and my app will show actions that I don't want to support.

I read the available documentation for the UIDocumentInteractionController and its delegate and I'm not able to find a another way to do what I do in the canPerformAction method.

Any ideas?

As a plus, it would be great to be able to filter apps like mail or twitter (that appears by default) but I guess that this is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is because Apple wants you to use the new *UIActivity* control.

Here it's the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Here it's a custom control developed to support many third party apps:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uiactivitycollection

And this question solves how could you make your own *UIActivity*:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12766330/736384

So, if you don't want the user can use *copy:* and *print:* methods just pass this activities to the *UIActivityViewController*, like this:

```
[activityView setExcludedActivityTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint, nil]];
```

All the default activities are listed at the bottom of the Apple's documentation link.

Comment: Hey.. thanks for the answer! I didn't see that coming jaja I will dig into this, but at a glance it seems to be the future. Thanks again!

Comment: so... if this were true, how would you open a file in another application (currently working with UIDocumentInteractionController's openWith… and QuickLookPreview?). AFAICS there's no support for this in UIActivityViewController (besides that UIActivityViewController has  some quite severe limitations as well)

Comment: Agree with auco - how can you now open in... xlxs or similar with iOS6?

Answer (score 8):

Agreed on the fact that deprecating 'canPerformAction' in the delegate is troublesome, we lost the fine grain control we used to have.

However, if all you want is to allow a document to be opened in another app, and wanted to remove Copy, Print and even Mail, I guess you are better off using `OpenIn` version of method to present the `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

i.e. for your `UIDocumentInteractionController` use `presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` or `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:`

(instead of `presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` or `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:`)

This way, by default, it will only show apps that can open your document, and hides Mail, Copy and Print.

Comment: This way makes rest of options unavailable too (FB, Twitter etc). What if someone wants to have OpenIn and FB..?

Comment: On the simulator there may be no installed apps to open the content and the menu will not show. See this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624218/presentopeninmenufrombarbuttonitem-doesnt-cause-menu-to-appear

Comment: It doesn't make the other options unavailable btw. And it's currently the _only_ way to Share to Instagram, for example. The sad state of iOS inter-app sharing/communications.