# How to share with messages, mail, print and copy

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've seen some apps that allow you to share content with ios's mail, messages, print and copy.

I see there is a project called sharekit that does something similar but integrates social network sharing. Personally I don't need the social sharing, so sharekit it probably overkill.

I just need to popup an actionsheet that will allowe me to pass some text for example to the mail app or the messages app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`MessageUI.framework`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html).

This framework contains:

- [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200)
  this class will allow your user to compose an e-mail.
- [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668) this class will allow your to compose a SMS message. MMS is not supported.

You will have to write the action sheet you self, but after the user made there choice you can create an instance of [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200) or [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668) and present it to the user.
Be aware that you will need to implement the [`MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate) and/or [`MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009669) to dismiss the view.

Comment: I think he's rather looking for the activy controller

Comment: Could be, but that is only available in iOS 6, also the question states that he only wants the mail and messages app.

Comment: Where does it say that in the question?

Comment: title :) "How to share with messages, mail, print and copy" and in the question body too *hehe*

Comment: Totally did not pay attention to the title, just the question. Your wright.

Answer (score 3):

Look my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975189/736384

I wrote about the new UIActivity control, It let you do all you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is integrate with Mail or Messages, use the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) classes respectively.

If you want to add support for Copy, Print, and other such "activities', take a look at the [documentation for UIActivity and UIActivityViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html).